# How do I send myself by mail a backup of a project using maven?

Tags: email, maven-2

Before my pet projects become serious enough to deserve real version control (and its headaches) I like to just email myself the sources after I worked for a while. How can this be done easily with maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use an [assembly using the `src` descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#src) to accomplish the wrapping up of all the sources and the pom.xml into a nice zip that you could then manually email to yourself.  If you wanted to get really fancy, you could use the Maven Ant plugin to call the [task that can send emails](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mail.html).

The core command you would run from the command line would be:

```
mvn assembly:assembly
```

The [assembly plugin usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) gives some great detail on using this plugin to aggregate everything into a bundle (zip).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you wouldn't set up version control, it is [amazingly simple](https://blog.codinghorror.com/setting-up-subversion-on-windows/).